# How to stop logs ( rsyslog ) for commands in linux?

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

I am using Linux system, when I run any command the command are getting logged, but not having root permissions I get following errors in my commands

> VD PLATFORM is : X14 KERNELARCH : arm chmod: changing permissions of
>   `/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt': Operation not permitted chmod:
>   changing permissions of`/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt':
>   Operation not permitted chmod: changing permissions of
>   `/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt': Operation not permitted chmod:
>   changing permissions of`/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt':
>   Operation not permitted chmod: changing permissions of
>   `/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt': Operation not permitted chmod:
>   changing permissions of`/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt':
>   Operation not permitted chmod: changing permissions of
>   `/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-cp.txt': Operation not permitted chmod:
>   changing permissions of`/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-cp.txt':
>   Operation not permitted chmod: changing permissions of
>   `/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-cp.txt': Operation not permitted chmod:
>   changing permissions of`/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-cp.txt':
>   Operation not permitted chmod: changing permissions of
>   `/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-cp.txt': Operation not permitted chmod:
>   changing permissions of`/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-cp.txt':
>   Operation not permitted chmod: changing permissions of
>   `/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt': Operation not permitted chmod:
>   changing permissions of`/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt':
>   Operation not permitted chmod: changing permissions of
>   `/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt': Operation not permitted chmod:
>   changing permissions of`/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt':
>   Operation not permitted chmod: changing permissions of
>   `/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt': Operation not permitted chmod:
>   changing permissions of`/var/log/USER_LOGS/09-18-14-make.txt':
>   Operation not permitted

I want to stop from saving the logs. I tried the following but no use

```
-bash-4.1$ sudo service rsyslog stop
Shutting down system logger:                               [OK]
```

Please help, how can I stop logging the commands.

Comment: u can use su (use root) or sudo chmod +x 777 filename

Answer (score -1):

sudo kill -KILL $(cat /var/run/rsyslogd.pid)